# Is There a Way to Delete All Empty Directories in My PC Using Command Line

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line, windows-7

I want to write a batch file to cleanup my whole C disk by deleting all empty directories in it using command line.
Is it doable?

Comment: Note that this would be a bad idea.  Some of those empty directories may be essential to the proper functioning of the operating system or applications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**edited** to addapt to comments (filter "problematic" folders) and because that when I was adapting it I realize there is a better solution (old solution still maintained at the end)

```
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    rem Configure where to start searching for empty folders
    set "root=c:\"

    rem We will use a temp file to store the full list of folders
    set "folderList=%temp%\%~nx0.%random%.tmp"

    rem Retrieve the full list of folders (except the problematic ones)
    rem and store it, sorted, inside the temporary file
    (   dir /s /b /ad "%root%" ^
        | findstr /v /l /i /b /c:"%programFiles:\=\\%" /c:"%systemRoot:\=\\%" ^
        | sort /r 
    )   > "%folderList%"

    rem Process the temporary file with the list of folders 
    rem "trying" to remove everything
    for /f "usebackq delims=" %%a in ("%folderList%") do (
        rd /q "%%~fa" >nul 2>nul && echo "%%~fa" removed
    )

    rem Remove the temporary file
    del /q "%folderList%" >nul 2>nul
```

To process the full list of folders in a system drive, the list can be huge. And there is a known problem with `for /f` retrieving data from a running process, so, i have changed the code to use a temporary file. Not as nice but it can be a lot faster.

What will be stored in the temporary file? The full list of folders under the indicated starting point. The list is filtered (`findstr`) to remove the `%programFolders%` and `%systemRoot%` folder from the list. Anything below it will be ignored.

The list is sorted in reverse order. As child folders have as prefix the full parent path, when reverse sorting the list, childs will appear before their parents. If all the childs are removed and the parent becomes empty, it will be also removed.

Once the list is generated, is is readed with a `for /f` command and a `rd` command is executed for each of the elements inside it. No check. Just `rd`. If the folder is not empty it can not be removed, there is no need to check the folder contents.

Once done, the temporary file is removed.

---

**OLD answer**. Less code but also less efficient and  more complicated. Better use the previous code

```
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    set "root=%cd%"
    for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /s /b /ad "%root%" ^| sort /r') do (
        dir /a /b "%%~fa" 2>nul |(set /p ".=" || echo rd /q "%%~fa" )
    )
```

The `for /f` command will execute a recursive `dir` to retrieve the full list of folders under the indicated starting point (change `root` variable to your needs), and sort this list in reverse order so the folder list can be processed from bottom to root. This step is necessary to ensure that removal of empty childs are executed before processing the parent so if all the descendants where removed the parent will also be removed (if empty, or course)

For each folder found, a `dir` command is executed and its output piped to a `set /p` command.

If the `dir` command generates data (the folder is not empty), the `set /p` will read information from the pipe and errorlevel will not be set.

But if the folder being processed is empty the `dir` will generate no output, the `set` will fail to retrieve data, errorlevel will be set and the `rd` command will be executed.

Directory removal operations are only echoed to console, if the output is correct, remove the `echo`

Comment: Seems that I have trouble understanding this properly, what do you mean by sort this list in reverse order? Also do I need to specify my directory at "root=%mydirectory%" ? sorry I very new to batch files

Comment: @Giancarlo, a recursive `dir` command will return a parent folder before all of its descendants. As all the descendants share the same parent prefix, sorting the list in descending order (what the `sort /r` does) ensures the deeper (child) folders are included in the list before their parents. So, if child removal generates an empty parent, the parent will be also removed. Yes, you have to change the variable to your needs, something like `set "root=c:\"` (`C` drive) or `set "root=%temp%"` (temporary folder). But as npocmaka indicates in its answer, be careful deleting folders in system drive.

Comment: thanks, can there be an addition to this code to exclude "Windows" folder?

Comment: Simply genius, exactly what I wanted. And this is very fast too. Thanks.